# Eclipse IDE hotkey or template for surrounding selected XML with processing instruction: <?ignore ... ?>

Tags: xml, eclipse

In the standard eclipse XML editor, the block comment hotkey has no way to handle nested comments, which makes commenting out large blocks of existing XML difficult. One way around this is to use a non existent processing instruction, which can be placed around any content:

```
<?ignore
<!-- comments can be here -->
?>
```

Is there a way to configure an XML template or hotkey that can apply this? I can't seem to get templates to work because the XML template doesn't have any way to *surround* the selected text with tags. Instead it duplicates the selection. Resulting in something like this:

```
<!-- comments can be here -->
<?ignore
<!-- comments can be here -->
?>
```

Comment: I can reproduce this in Eclipse WTP's XML editor with the template `<?ignore${word_selection}?>`. The duplication seems to me to be a bug. Please makes sure it has been reported to Eclipse WTP, best with a patch.

Comment: @howlger Not sure if this is a bug or working as intended, but submitted it either way: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=579740